# Scrabble Board in VB.net

Tags: vb.net

I would like to know how to iteratively loop through textboxes in my game of Scrabble. I have a 15x15 grid of textboxes, each with the name Grid(number), where (number) is the number of 1-225 textboxes.
Here is an example: How can I change this so that I can loop through every textbox on the board(Grid1 - Grid225) so that whichever textbox on the board I click will get the same text as the textbox CurrentPiece without doing this same code for every single textbox?

```
Private Sub Grid1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Grid1.Click
    Grid1.Text = CurrentPiece.Text
```

Answer (score 3):

Build a method like this:

```
Private Sub GridSpaceClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
     Dim currentPiece As TextBox = DirectCast(sender, TextBox)

     '...
End Sub
```

And then loop through all your text boxes to connect that to their click events, like this:

```
For Each box As TextBox In Grid1.Controls.OfType(Of TextBox)()
    AddHandler box.Click, AddressOf GridSpaceClick
Next box
```